# Javascript not working on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, webpack

I am developing a large project on Laravel with a bundle of pure JS + jQuery. In the browser everything works, in general, as expected, but the problems begin when I try to enter the site from a mobile phone. Tested on iPhone 5c iOS9 and Samsung Galaxy Core Prime, version android - 5.1.1. When you click on any button on the site, it will only go through the links, and where an action is expected (for example, the appearance of a modal window) - nothing works here.

I use webpack to build JS, I have some code on the site written on ES2015, but webpack successfully transports all this code to ES 5.1. For the whole project I have one large JS-file, but there can not be conflicts, because my code runs depending on the page that the user comes in (the path I take from window.location, and depending on which page the user comes to, those functions work out).

I tried to comment out all the code, and call up a test alert, (at first I thought maybe the js-file just turned out great), the alert worked, but for some reason the code in the webpack wrapper refuses to work.

If someone is confronted with a problem of this kind, or perhaps knows what the cause of the problem might be, tell me, please.

At the moment I only have a free link from my hosting where I uploaded the project.

Link: http://wte.andmars.beget.tech/

Console (errors): http://joxi.ru/krD66vWiEE8JJ2

Comment: First of all, I can see that your file `http://andmars.beget.tech.loc/app/img/main/numbers.png` is not available. Maybe this is the reason?

Comment: open your site using google chrome, then activate the debugger (F12), perform emulation to your device, then you maybe will be able to see console errors.

Comment: On the android phone you can switch on debugging and then connect your mobile chrome browser to a desktop one to do some remote debugging. It will help greatly. For iPhone I think there's no similar equivalent way for Safari (which is what iPhone users would probably use by default)

Comment: benchpresser, tried to emulate devices in Google Chrome - everything works correctly, modal windows appear when you click on the necessary elements. Everything, in general, works well. But on the mobile phone - no.

Comment: fixed the problem with numbers.png, but the main problem remained.

Answer (score 0):

The error is related to the dns, since `.loc` is not a valid tld.